# How to select a dropdown with optgroup in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, select, drop-down-menu

```
<select class="ms-crm-SelectBox" sort="ascending" defaultselected="-1" id="advFindE_fieldListFLDCTL" style="" xpath="1">
    <optgroup id="fld" label="Fields">
        <option value="xyz_accountnumber" datatype="nvarchar" maxlength="100" title="Account Number">Account Number</option>
        <option value="xyz_addsource" datatype="nvarchar" maxlength="100" title="Add Source">Add Source</option>
        <option value="xyz_addsourceleadid" datatype="nvarchar" maxlength="100" title="Add Source Lead ID">Add Source Lead ID</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I have trying to select **Account Number**,I am using python

```
dropdown_list = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#advFindE_fieldListFLDCTL'))
dropdown_list.select_by_value('xyz_accountnumber')
```

I am getting the below error

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
> element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not
> be m.

Can you help?

Comment: Usually you don't require to click the dropdown, but just give it a try. Click on dropdown_list first and then use select_by_value

Comment: Is it a public website?

Comment: It is dynamics CRM advance filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ms-crm-SelectBox')
element.click()

option = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='xyz_addsource']")
option.click()
```

Is this what you are trying to do?